# lodash comparing objects in an array and create a new object based on this comparison

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have an array of objects which is in below format:

```
var res = [
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 13:30", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 14:00", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 14:30", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 15:00", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 20:00", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 20:30", Status: "free" },
];
```

Now I want to create an object which split this array of objects into 2 array of objects in a way that if the StartTimes have 30 minutes different they can stay together and if not I'll move on and create a new array which will look like this:

```
var res = [
  [
    { StartTime: "04/29/2020 13:30", Status: "free" },
    { StartTime: "04/29/2020 14:00", Status: "free" },
    { StartTime: "04/29/2020 14:30", Status: "free" },
    { StartTime: "04/29/2020 15:00", Status: "free" },
  ],
  [
    { StartTime: "04/29/2020 20:00", Status: "free" },
    { StartTime: "04/29/2020 20:30", Status: "free" },
  ],
];
```

I'm using moment.js to find the difference between 2 dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in vanilla JavaScript, something like:

```js
var res = [
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 13:30", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 14:00", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 14:30", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 15:00", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 20:00", Status: "free" },
  { StartTime: "04/29/2020 20:30", Status: "free" },
];

let j = 0, result = [], previous;
for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  let current = new Date(res[i].StartTime);
  if (previous && current.getTime() - previous.getTime() > 30 * 60 * 1000) j++;
  (result[j] = result[j] || []).push(res[i]);
  previous = current;
}

console.log(result);
```